# Delta function limit definition in higher dimensions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I know the following definition of the $\delta$-function: Given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\delta(x)=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\epsilon|x|^{\epsilon-1}.
\end{equation}

I came across a similar looking definition in higher dimensions. Given $x\in \mathbb{R}^4$ we supposedly have
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\delta^{(4)}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \epsilon |x|^{\epsilon-4},
\end{equation}
where $|x|$ is the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^4$. I can imagine a generalisation to any dimension
\begin{equation}
\delta^{(D)}(x)=f(D)\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \epsilon |x|^{\epsilon-D}.
\end{equation}
Is there a way to prove these $D$-dimensional identities from the one-dimensional one? I would have guessed that $f(D)$ is related to the area of the $D$-sphere $S_{D-1}=\frac{2\pi^{D/2}}{\Gamma(D/2)}$, but that doesn't quite match up for $D=1$.

Comment: The definition of the $\delta^{(D)}$ "function" is that for any continuous function $f$, $\int_{\mathbb R^D} f(x) \delta^{(D)}(x) \text{d}^D x = f(0)$. From this you can deduce the different formulas you are using

Comment: In the one-dimensional case, the $2$ in the $1/2$ is the "volume"  of the $0$-sphere, which consists of just two points... So the pattern does persist, after all.

Comment: In general the delta function can be approximated by rescaling any nonnegative function with total mass $1$. If $\int f = 1$, then $$ \delta(x) = \lim {\epsilon\rightarrow 0} f(\epsilon^{-1}x)\epsilon^{-n}.$$

Comment: Thanks everybody, I see how it works now. And indeed $f(D)=1/S_{D-1}$ as expected.